# R package building: importing functions with identical names

Tags: r, package, conflict, compiled

I am building a R package importing two functions entitled "rngseed" from two different R packages (entitled cat and mix). Unfortunately, such a package cannot be deposited on the CRAN because of the conflict with the names of imported functions. My question is how to solve this problem.

My idea was to copy one of both (the one from the R pacakge cat) and include it in my R folder under another name. The function is as follows:

```
function (seed) 
{
    seed <- as.integer(seed)
    if (seed <= 0) 
        stop("Seed must be a positive integer")
    tmp <- .Fortran("rngs", seed, PACKAGE = "cat")
    invisible()
}
```

I understand it is based on a Fortran subroutine. I am not very comfortable with including Fortran or C functions in my package. After several readings, I essentially tried to modify the NAMESPACE file by adding a line like useDynLib(cat,rngs), but I seems not relevant since when installing the package on my laptop, I obtain an error "the DLL 'cat' is not found".

I hope my post is clear enough. Thank you very much for your help to solve my issue, using a copy of one of both functions or in another manner.

Best,

Vincent

Comment: In https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#useDynLib, it says you can do `useDynLib(foo, myRoutine_sym = myRoutine, myOtherRoutine)`; with that, you might be able to do something like `useDynLib(cat, cat_rngs=rngs); useDynLib(mix, mix_rngs=rngs)`; the `.Call` will then support `.Call(cat_rngs, ..)`, but I don't know offhand if that would also be supported as `.Fortran(cat_rngs, ..)`, both untested. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you r2vans for your help. By adding ``useDynLib(cat, cat_rngs=rngs); useDynLib(mix, mix_rngs=rngs)```` in the NAMESPACE file, and adding the following function in the R folder ```rngseedcat <- function (seed) 
{
  seed <- as.integer(seed)
  if (seed <= 0) 
    stop("Seed must be a positive integer")
  tmp <- .Call("cat_rngs", seed, PACKAGE = "mypackage")
  invisible()
}``` I obtain the same error, but maybe is something wrong...

Comment: The `;` semi-colon was meant to be a newline, I don't think `NAMESPACE` supports `;`-delimited lines? Sorry about that, my bad. If you fix that and it still doesn't work, then I think I've exhausted my level of support here, I'm not a regularly use of `useDynLib`. Good luck!

Comment: Indeed, I used two different lines (and not semicolon). Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this at too low of a level.  It works for me if I declare `cat` and `mix` as imports, and in my `NAMESPACE` file I have this:

```
importFrom(cat, catseed = rngseed)
importFrom(mix, mixseed = rngseed)
```

The fact that those functions call Fortran functions internally doesn't matter if I'm only going to call them as R functions.